# Ubuntu Ignores $HOME/.dmrc File

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I'm not sure what I did to cause this, but every time I log in to Ubuntu it tells me that "User's $HOME/.dmrc file is being ignored." The message goes on to suggest that it is probably a permissions problem. However, my .dmrc file is owned by the correct user, and that user has read, write, and execute permissions on the file. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=758126

Comment: What does ls -l display from /home/

Comment: @Gren: Every result returned with `ls -l` shows the correct user as the owner, with at least `rw` permissions for the owner. When I run `ls -al`, `.dbus` and `.wireshark` are owned by `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid off the execute permission:

```
chmod -x .dmrc
```

If that doesn't work, try making the file only readable by yourself:

```
chmod go-rw .dmrc
```

Another Edit:

After Googling around for a bit, it seems that the permissions on your home directory might also be a factor. What is the output of `ls -dl $HOME` on your system?

Comment: Didn't work, even though the permissions for that file are now `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: Ah! My .dmrc is only readable by myself. I've change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit until now. My `.dmrc` permissions are now `-rw-------`, but it still doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Wow. What a stubborn beast gdm seems to be. I've edited my answer once again.